# How can I detect if my master page is invoked via a Webforms or MVC page in my MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, master-pages

The project I am working on was a project that was originally WebForms and later migrated to Asp.Net MVC.  3 pages are still using Webforms and it's not worth the effort to rewrite them.

To prevent having to maintain two separate master pages that look identical I have two master pages, `MVC.Master` and `Webforms.Master`.  `Webforms.Master` has `MVC.Master` set as its master page, so that whenever I add a new tool link to my menu it always shows no matter if the user is looking at a Webforms or MVC page.  The `Webforms.Master` has nothing but an ajaxToolkit Script manager on it.

Everything has been working fine until now, where I am adding Telerik support.  The problem is that you cannot use Html helpers in WebForm pages, as you get the exception `A ViewMasterPage can be used only with content pages that derive from ViewPage or ViewPage<TModel>.`

Since I do not care if Telerik's script and stylesheet registrars are run for Webform pages, I ideally would like to do something like

```
<% if (!PageIsWebforms) 
   {
       Html.Telerik().....
   }
%>
```

Unfortunately, I can't think of a good way to successfully determine if the inner page is a WebForms page or not. Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC pages inherit something other than System.Web.UI.Page, could you test `Page is System.Web.MVC.ViewPage`.
You could make that a property to make the markup easier.

Comment: That worked.  If the page is an MVC page, then the `Page` property inherits from `System.Web.MVC.ViewPage`, so checking if `Page is System.Web.MVC.ViewPage` tells me if the page is MVC or not .  Thanks!

Comment: @KallDrexx, a more direct test would be to check `Page is System.Web.MVC.ViewPage` (notice **is** not **as**). I've edited my answer to include the actual MVC page type.